# How Frequent is Centos C5 Testing Repo updated?

Tags: security, centos

May I know how frequent does Centos Dev Repo (C5 Testing Repo) update the patches? or Where can I find this information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official information on the subject, but if you need some newer software versions, you can get them from RPMForge. Automated RPMForge repository installation script is available here: http://wiki.centos.org/VladislavRastrusny/AutoRPMForgeRepo.

If some packages are protected when you try to update them, you can use

```
--disablerepo=* --enablerepo=rpmforge
```

switches to temporarily disable all repositories and their protection.